# Which SVN hostings allow repository import/export

Tags: svn

There are many subversion hosting companies, some free, some charge a bit/a lot. When google first offered GMail, they allowed users to come and to leave, unlike most other major providers. You could export all your email to another account, etc.

Are there anything similar in SVN hosting market? I only found xp-dev.com to offer that, but they are extremely cumbersome to use. Which companies allow you to take your data and go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) allows both import and export of Subversion repositories.

Answer (score 3):

With [svnsync](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt), I'd be curious as to how they could stop you.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleCode allows this: you can do pretty much what you want with your SVN space.  Of course, this is a public space...

I use Subclipse plugin under Eclipse and I don't recall having any problems importing/exporting my spaces on GoogleCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be absolutely sure to be in control, use a virtual server solution like e.g. [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/)
and set up Subversion yourself. It's quite simple.